# Using ftype to Declare Functions in Common Lisp

Tags: type-systems, common-lisp

[The Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/type.html) discusses how to use `ftype` to declare the inputs and outputs of functions. In compilers with a lot of type inferencing like SBCL, this would seem to offer a lot of support during development at both compile time and run time for error checking and generating efficient compiled code. (The extent of run time checks seem easily adjusted by changing compiler policy.)

However, much of the professional code I've looked at doesn't use such declarations. For example, Edi Weitz's popular [cl-ppcre](https://github.com/edicl/cl-ppcre) doesn't (although he does `declaim` the types of parameters). Special efficiency considerations obviously call for declarations in hot spots, but wouldn't program-wide `ftype` declamations also be a significant help during development? Or is this overkill?

Comment: One drawback: one would actually need to understand type declarations in Common Lisp, which can be surprisingly difficult (example: arrays and vectors).

Comment: A good start on this for me was your graphic at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540781/common-lisp-type-vs-class-distinctions